# Sharepoint 2010 Standard

Tags: sharepoint-2010

SharePoint 2010 standard on 64 bit gives configuration wizard error at point of web app creation.

Links in central administration are generating error.
example manage application service cannot be opened.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Its hard to help you with the level of information you have provided.

Comment: We need more information. What do you see int he logs? What error message?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the email asking for details.

Log in 14 Hive has the following re-occuring  error...

OWSTIMER.EXE (0x0F24)                   0x0E90 SharePoint Foundation         Unified Logging Service       2159 Critical Event 5586 (SharePoint Foundation) of severity 'Error' occurred 50 more time(s) and was suppressed in the event log
psconfigui.exe (0x0B50)                 0x0D90 SharePoint Foundation         Unified Logging Service       b8fx High     ULS Init Completed (psconfigui.exe, onetnative.dll)
psconfigui.exe (0x0B50)                 0x0D90 SharePoint Foundation         General                       0000 Medium   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation log file
psconfigui.exe (0x0B50)                 0x0D90 SharePoint Foundation         Topology                       apzn Medium   Diagnostics settings: 32768

Copy paste is just the first 4 lines from the log.

thanks